# Rewriting Tikhonov regularization in block matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning linear algebra, and I came across the following statement:

\begin{align*}
    \|Ax - b\|^2 + \lambda^2 \|x^2\| = \left\|\begin{bmatrix}A  \\ \lambda I \end{bmatrix}x - \begin{bmatrix} b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}  \right\|^2
\end{align*}

This is not clear to me how the right-hand side is the same as the expression on the left. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can try to write the norms as sums of squares and you will see that both sides are equal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is helpful to use [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) to observe that
$$
\pmatrix{A\\ \lambda I}x = \pmatrix{Ax\\ (\lambda I)x} = \pmatrix{Ax\\ \lambda x}.
$$
With that, I believe that the statement should be clear.